# How can I compare big files under Windows?

Tags: windows, diff

I'd like to compare two files under Windows, each about 1Gb in size. I tried [Total Commander](http://ghisler.com/) and [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), but both ended with *Out of memory* errors.

I'm running Vista Home Premium 64bit with 8GB of RAM so memory should not be an issue.

Comment: Memory _will_ be an issue with 32-bit applications, which not so much run out of memory, but rather address space.

Comment: This is an ancient post, but it isn't clear whether the objective is to determine **IF** they're different or **HOW** they're different.

Comment: @fixer1234: If somebody mentions WinMerge it is totally clear that the question is *HOW* the files are different. BTW: This question exactly matches the pattern `"I have <problem-x> that I don't know how to solve.` mentioned in the meta answer how to ask for software. Therefore closing this question was IMHO wrong.

Comment: @Robert, the title is "what program to use", and the question is a description of what it needs to do.  To me, that's a product recommendation request.  It also attracted 12 answers (1 deleted), that mostly interpreted the question that way and produced a list of favorite programs (some low quality posts), which is what we're trying to avoid.  To your WinMerge comment, people use the tools at hand, not always to take advantage of all the available features.  Some of the answers interpreted the question as "if" rather than "how", and the OP offers no clarification in comments or the question.

Comment: Just tried WinMerge 2.16, it has diffed two 250 MB files in a few seconds

Answer (score 30):

What about just using `fc` or `comp`?

Both are included in Windows and should have no problems handling large files. In fact, 1 GiB is actually a pretty small file.

Comment: `fc` works fine with such large files indeed. Its comparison algorithm is a bit sloppy though.

Comment: I just tried fc on a 58 million lines file (3+gb) and it reported a mismatch around the 87 millionth line. The mismatch was correct, just the reported line was messed up.

Comment: Old Post, but fc with their options like /b or /W should work

Answer (score 7):

My (ASCII) files were each about 1.2 GB.

I tried:

- NotePad++
- MultiEdit
- Beyond Compare 3
- ExamDiff Pro
- DiffMerge
- WinMerge
  and they all failed (couldn't load the file or crashed)

The one that worked for me at the end was ... [PilotEdit](http://www.pilotedit.com/) x64 6.2.0.

It took some time to load each file and even more to do the comparison, but once it was done, it worked perfectly fine and just the way I had seen it in MultiEdit and NotePad++ before. Jumped between diff blocks, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I use [HashTab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/), worked fine for 1 GB files the last time I needed them and it's free.

Comment: -1 as although HashTab is great, it's not an answer to the question

Comment: Dude, not comparing whether the file has changed. We know the file has changed, but to compare what's the change.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find the differences rather than simply find out if the files are the same (via a checksum) then you could split the files first and then try a file comparison.
[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) File Manager will split files into 650Mb chunks (File > Split file...) which should then open in [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)

Comment: Did you know TC also splits files?  `File > Split File...`

Answer (score 3):

You could try a command line diff tool or [DiffUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm). [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/) also has a comparison tool integrated it the files are text.

If you just need to detmine if the files are different (not what the differences are) use a [checksum](http://www.openoffice.org/dev_docs/using_md5sums.html#win) comparison tool that uses MD5 or SHA1. I use [digestIT 2004](http://digestit.kennethballard.com/download.html).

Answer (score 3):

I use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) for this. It is a very good tool for file comparison and directory synchronization (although it is not free :-(

Comment: It is very good value for the price and "A single user license covers one person using BC on any number of computers"

http://www.scootersoftware.com/shop.php?zz=pricing

Comment: Beyond Compare doesn't work for binary files above 500MB...

Answer (score 3):

Try [ExamDiff (Pro)](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiffpro.asp).

Comment: For just comparing two text files in a graphical way the free version ExamDiff seems to be also a candidate.

Comment: 2 files of nearly 200mb and I got a 128mb memory limit error.. Ditched it

Answer (score 2):

[KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) now has a 64 bit version which works for large files.

This is an old question, but I had the same problem when attempting to use KDiff3.

I was looking for a free option that wasn't a trial or only for non-commercial use.  I discovered that I was using the 32 bit version of KDiff3 and it now has a 64 bit version.  Installing it allowed me to diff much larger files.

Comment: tried kdiff3 64bit, it crashes on 2 1.6G files.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Hex Workshop](http://www.hexworkshop.com/) for comparing large files at hex level. Sure, it's not free, but it's worth every penny. There's plenty of hex editors, hex calculators, file comparison, etc. but this is one of those cases where the whole is much more than the sum of its parts

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are both 32-bit apps, so even on a 64-bit platform they are bound to a 2GB max memory usage limit. Though, you would think they would have another way of handling this, such as paging the extra data.

Comment: Yep, I can't believe they are loading whole files into memory...

Comment: 2 GB max memory limit isn't relevant; even for a 32-bit program, it has the ability to stream in sections of a text file at a time. -- There's no reason a text file needs to be loaded entirely into memory for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I use ExamDiff [www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp) but I am not sure if it will work for ~1GB files.