# Alternative to WinMerge in windows

Tags: text-editors, merge, comparison, winmerge

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is a good text comparison tool for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/56603/what-is-a-good-text-comparison-tool-for-windows)
>   [What program to use to compare big files under Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/34962/what-program-to-use-to-compare-big-files-under-windows)

Anyone know any good ones? I'm looking for a particuar one, but I can't remember what it was called (not notepad++)

Comment: Duplicate Question: http://superuser.com/questions/34962/what-program-to-use-to-compare-big-files-under-windows

Comment: I use DevArt's Code Compare, the free version. Looks perfect to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use Beyond Compare from Scooter Software (which i think is awesome) or you could use [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) which is open source and also very good