# compare and find differences of 2 huge text files (50 gb)

Tags: cygwin, diff, textfiles

I want to find the differences between two text files (more than 50 GB) each.

I tried `diff` but, I got `memory exhausted` problem.

I am using Windows7. My code is in PHP. I was calling diff from my php as:

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'diff $text_files_path/$OldDatabaseFile.txt $text_files_path/$NewDatabaseFile.txt >  $text_files_path/TempDiff_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt 2>&1'");
```

Someone told me about `rdiff` that generates signature and delta but, I did not test it because I do not know how to begin.

From where can I install it? From where can I run it? From windows cmd or cygwin cmd?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What program to use to compare big files under Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/34962/what-program-to-use-to-compare-big-files-under-windows)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I don't want a GUI program! I want to write a command that call such utility in my php code.

Comment: There are many answers there, and many are not GUI programs.

Comment: Sorry but, I try the "not GUI programs": fc and comp and not what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `--speed-large-files` switch to `diff`? It should waste less memory:

```
diff --speed-large-files [...]
```

From manual page for `diff`:

> **--speed-large-files**
>
> assume large files and many scattered small changes

Comment: Yes. I try it. The same prob!

Answer (score 1):

## wxHexEditor

wxHexEditor is both free and able to Diff large files up to 2^64 bytes (2 ExaByte). Has a GUI. Cross-platform. Lots of features.

To get it for free, choose one of the following options:

- Option: [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxhexeditor/)
- Option: [GitHub](https://github.com/EUA/wxHexEditor)
- Option: Both Debian & Ubuntu repositories

---

Below is the same suggestion as above. But with details if you're interested in those.

## Screenshot

[image]

## Strength

• Hexadecimal (Hex) Editor. Which is helpful for doing reverse Engineering.

• Cross-platform. Linux, Mac OS, Windows

• Easy to use Graphical User Interface (GUI)

• Supports very large files up to 2^64 bytes (2 ExaByte)

• Compare two large files side by side (diff). Optionally list and search all diff.

• Very fast search

• Use small amount of RAM

• Do not create temporary files. So it used a very small amount of storage space.

• Dark or bright theme

• Multilingual 15 languages

• Open source. If you are not familiar with "open source", it means this software has both stronger security & stronger privacy. Because its code is publicly available for review and contributions to GitHub at https://github.com/EUA/wxHexEditor or at SourceForge at https://sourceforge.net/p/wxhexeditor/code/

• Attractive GNU General Public License version 2. This means the software code of this extension is owned and supported by a friendly not-for-profit community. Instead of a for-profit corporation. https://github.com/EUA/wxHexEditor/blob/master/LICENSE

## Challenge

• Confusion between the two code repositories. At the time of this writing, August 2021, the GitHub repository seems to be more recent. As it was last updated in 2021 at https://github.com/EUA/wxHexEditor
In comparison, the SourceForge repository at https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxhexeditor/ was last update of wxHexEditor was December 31st, 2017.

## Show Your Support

• If you enjoy this application, show your support to the authors & contributors with:

___• Donation at https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?item_name=Donation+to+wxHexEditor&cmd=_donations&business=erdem.ua%40gmail.com

___• Support with ticket at https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxhexeditor/support

___• Support with forum at https://sourceforge.net/p/wxhexeditor/discussion/

___• Patch at https://sourceforge.net/p/wxhexeditor/patches/

## Using

• wxHexEditor 0.23
• Debian 10 Buster
• GNOME 3.30.2

Comment: Is it possible to run it without a GUI, as this is a requirement by the OP?

Comment: Yes it possible to run wxHexEditor without a GUI. But partly only. 

Using the OP PHP or any Terminal/Console, wxHexEditor is able to both be started and open a specific file. All the above without GUI. The command is: 
wxHexEditor "<PATH>/<FILE>"

But that's pretty much it. For advanced operations, you need to use the GUI. Any volunteer interested to contribute additional operations without GUI for wxHexEditor? If yes, your contribution is welcome at https://github.com/EUA/wxHexEditor

Answer (score 0):

#### From where can I install it (`rdiff`)?

> Someone told me about `rdiff` that generates signature and delta but, I did not test it because I do not know how to begin. From where can I install it? and from where can I run it? From windows `cmd` or cygwin cmd?

[Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) includes `rdiff`. It is in the `rdiff-1.0.0-1` package.

---

#### From where can I run it (`rdiff`)?

> Someone told me about `rdiff` that generates signature and delta but, I did not test it because I do not know how to begin. From where can I install it? and from where can I run it? From windows `cmd` or cygwin cmd?

You run `rdiff` a Cygwin `bash` shell.

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'diff $text_files_path/$OldDatabaseFile.txt $text_files_path/$NewDatabaseFile.txt >  $text_files_path/TempDiff_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt 2>&1'");
```

A command similar to the above (replacing `diff` with `rdiff` and modifying the command options as necessary) should work.

---

#### How can I find out which package `rdiff` is in?

The easiest way to find the package containing a particular command is to use [Cygwin Package Search](http://cygwin.com/packages/) web page:

> [image]

Scroll to the bottom of the page:

> [image]

Click on [rdiff-1.0.0-1](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Frdiff%2Frdiff-1.0.0-1&grep=rdiff):

> [image]

This confirms that `rdiff-1.0.0-1` is the correct package to install.

See [Installing and Updating Cygwin Packages](https://cygwin.com/install.html) for installation instructions.